# Redirect www to non-www with cloud storage bucket static site

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cname, no-www

I have a static site hosted on google cloud storage bucket.

In front of my bucket I have cloudflare dns.

Storage bucket is `example.com`

Cloudflare settings:
`CNAME > @ > c.storage.googleapis.com > TTL automatic`

Question is how to implement a redirect from `www.example.com` to `example.com`, because now `www.example.com` resolves to 404 error page?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Cloudflare settings, but you should be able to do this by just adding a CNAME record for www that also points to c.storage.googleapis.com. Have you tried that?

Comment: I'm also facing this issue, but what happens if you do what @ChristopherP says is that you get a `<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>` error, because GCP will try to map your www.domain.com to a bucket called www.domain.com, which doesn't exist because you've only made a domain.com bucket

Comment: @PGT - you just set the CNAME www to c.storage.googleapis.com in cloudflare DNS and then it works.

Comment: @proruzi: bucket doesn't exist, I have the naked domain bucket. I eventually solved this using cloudflare page rules

Answer (score 4):

Create a **Page Rule** on CloudFlare:

- **URL:** www.example.com/*
- **Setting:** Forwarding URL (301 or 302)
- **Destination:** https://example.com/$1

Comment: IMPORTANT: Use `www.example.com*` instead of `www.example.com/*` or else it won't work for redirecting just the domain (without a resource path)